# JSON dimension too deep

Tags: php, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I get an additional arraydimension and I don't really know why. This is the php code I use for my multidimensional array.

```
$json_arr = array(
        "a" => "0",
        "b" => 1,
        "c" => 2);

$json_arr_d = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$rows*$cols; $i++) {
    $json_arr_d[] = array(
        "d1" => "$i",
        "d2" => "0",
        "d3" => rand(0, 2)
    );
}

$json_arr_e = array();
for ($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {
    $json_arr_e[] = array(
        "e1" => $i,
        "e2" => "0",
        "e3" => rand(0, 1),
        "e4" => false
    );
}

$json_arr[] = array("d" => $json_arr_d);
$json_arr[] = array("e" => $json_arr_e);

$json = json_encode($json_arr);
```

As you can see in the following result. There are additional layers [0] and [1] for my d & e array.

```
{  
   "a":"ABXD",
   "b":5,
   "c":6,
   "0":{  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
      "d":[  
         {  
            "d1":"0",
            "d2":"1",
            "d3":1
         },
         {  
            "d1":"1",
            "d2":"2",
            "d3":1,
         }
   },
   "1":{  // HERE IS THE PROBLEM
      "d":[  
         {  
            "d1":"0",
            "d2":"1",
            "d3":1,
            "d4":false
         },
         {  
            "d1":"1",
            "d2":"2",
            "d3":0,
            "d4":false
         }
   ]
}
```

Maybe I am to sleepy already and it is a pretty simple solution or my way to add the arrays is fundamentally wrong.

Comment: @Barmar I said you, I didn't mean to answer. `:)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't push onto the array, assign to the key you want.

```
$json_arr['d'] = $json_arr_d;
$json_arr['e'] = $json_arr_e;
```

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much!